# Are magento 1.3 books still worth the money?

Tags: php, magento

I am diving into magento programming and am looking for a structured introduction. Unfortunately I do not find much, but some books on magento 1.3 (I'm not looking for administration, theming or how to increase sales, I'm looking for sys architecture, extension dev and so on).

Since I'm coming from typo3, I know that two years can include game changers (extbase in typo3).

So, are books for 1.3 still recommendable? Are there any other structural resources that go beyond HELLO WORLD?

EDIT: I'm as well looking for hints regarding the main gaps between 1.3 and 1.7 and how to fill them.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, buy them. Of course stuff has changed, been removed or added but the core features you touch while working with magento remain still the same. You can learn all about the folder structur and codepools from the very beginning, e.g. and i believe unless there is a new magento version made from scratch that is something that will never change. So go ahead.

Comment: Could you point out the main parts that have changed since? So that I recognize them while reading and can look for resources to fill the gap.

Comment: in about 90% only the inner core has changed and that is something you never touch. Except on that were there a lot of bugfixes and new features, but still the functionality you touch remains the same

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to start with [Alan Storm's tutorials on Magento](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) and then go through a book. Anyway, if you manage to survive those tutorials and you have time to poke around Magento's source code, you'll be able to do many things with this framework.

Comment: This looks really interesting, thanks for the link.

Comment: Alan Storm's book, No Frills Layout is recommended

Comment: It's about layout not ext dev, right?

Comment: +1. His tutorials generally detail fundamentals that are useful no matter what you are working on in Magento. Books based on 1.3 will provide some insights as well. For my money (though my employer paid for it) the Magento U training is by far the most helpful of all, especially once you have some working knowledge of the framework. And you might even have a conversation about how to be an ostrich jockey.